# BigInteger.mod in java equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, biginteger, modulo

In java:

```
b1 = new BigInteger("-3896390610386937370574318634931111609708735540536209530871");
b2 = new BigInteger("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000");

// apply mod() method
BigInteger result = b1.mod(b2);
```

`result = 425681365068888390291264459463790469129`

While I am trying to write the same code in c# I am getting the other value

**In C#**

```
BigInteger b1 = 
BigInteger.Parse("-3896390610386937370574318634931111609708735540536209530871");
BigInteger b2 = BigInteger.Parse("1000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
BigInteger result = BigInteger.Remainder( b1, b2);
```

`result = -574318634931111609708735540536209530871`

I also tried with `BigInteger % operator`. I am not sure which method or operator to use to get the same value like in java.

Comment: This should fix it: `b1 % b2 < 0 ? (b1 % b2) + b2 : b1 % b2;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write:

```
b1 % b2 < 0 ? (b1 % b2) + b2 : b1 % b2;
```

Wrap to your own method:

```cs
public static int Mod(int b1, int b2)
{
    var r = b1 % b2;
    return r < 0 ? r + b2 : r;
}
```

Comment: I have two comments. (1) In case both operands `b1` and `b2` are negative, this is likely not what we need. (2) Of course the signature of the method should be `BigInteger Mod(BigInteger, BigInteger)` in the case the asker wants.